# Why Spark is very slow to run the same command?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that I've created it from hive table as following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import sqlContext.implicits._

val hiveObj = new HiveContext(sc)
val df = hiveObj.sql("select * from database.table")
```

the `df` here is about 2 millions rows;
So I created a sub dataframe `subdf` from the  `df` above and I limited the numbre of rows to 500 on it as following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand

val subdf =df.orderBy(rand()).limit(500)
```

now when I triesd to display the `df` rows it took me couple second and when I tried to do the samething with `subdf` it took me literally more than 10 min despite of the numbre of rows is extremely small.

```
df.select("col").show() //2sec
subdf.select("col").show() //more than 10 min
```

could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here !!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is obvious when you think about amount of required to compute the result.

- The first statement has to check only the minimum number of partitions (possibly one) to collect 20 records (default number of rows returned by `show`)
- The second statement has to:

  - Load all records.
  - Find first 500 records from each partition, according to ordering.
  - Shuffle the records to a single partition.
  - Get final 500 records.
  - Print 20 records.

The first scenario is almost as cheap as it gets, the cost of the second one would be exceeded only by a full shuffle.

Comment: a)  `df.orderBy(rand()).limit(500)` is lazy (transformations). It doesn't do anything else than preparing execution plan. b) Partitions, like RDD partitions.

Comment: How can I make this code work in a small lapse of time?

Comment: To get random sample (is it your goal) you have to cosnider all records, so I don't see faster track.